# The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null

Tags: c#, .net

I received the error  System.IO.FileNotFoundException with The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)":null.

Howvere I do not know which module failed to find. No innerexception either, any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of any other information, I suggest using something like [sysinternals process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out what file is being looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10 64 bit. I cannot run or debug my C# application. I solved the problem by copying C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr71.dll 
file from my old computer with Windows 7 to the new one to folder with Windows 10.